# Virtual IP Addresses

Tags: vpn, ip-address

I am in Canada and wish to stream "all" Netflix content so that I have available the selections in the US while I am in Canada.

I have heard of the VIP but to be quite honest have not got a clue about how to go about initiating one and then maintaining it.

Anybody out there have any suggestions and/or advice?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are asking about is "virtual private networks" or VPNs (which are virtual in the sense that they don't have dedicated physical links, but go on top of another network, usually Internet). Connecting to a VPN may allow you to use Internet through somebody else's computer, causing websites to see only that computer's IP address.

- [You: 192.0.2.1] ⇄ [VPN server: 203.0.113.1] ⇄ [Web server: 198.51.100.1]

There exist commercial VPN providers which offer connections for the purposes of hiding your IP address and/or encrypting the traffic; they can be found by searching for "VPN provider" or similar queries.

Be aware that using a VPN for this purpose may be a violation of [Netflix terms of use](https://signup.netflix.com/TermsOfUse).